# VSTS Restrict access to sensitive work items

Tags: permissions, azure-devops

***Foreword:*** I've searched around on this question a fair bit and found answers which are close to a solution, but not what I'm looking for. So here I am, and I hope someone can help me. I'm relatively new to VSTS, so be gentle (or at least constructive) ;P

**The Question:** I'm looking for a way to restrict access to specific tickets (NOT by ticket type) that contain NDA protected data, whilst keeping them in the same backlog and iterations as the rest of the tickets related to a project.

We have many different NDA protected customers, so whilst creating a new ticket type per NDA, and restricting access to this, *could* work, it's not the solution I'm looking for.
Alternatively, I'm barking up the wrong tree, and there is an entirely different and "better way" to support this use-case?

**Edit 1 - More info:** Let's say I have 1 backlog for a product. It contains only 2 work items. It's important there is only 1 backlog for planning and overview by a product owner.

One of the two work items contains sensitive information only half the development team should have visibility to. How do I keep both tickets in the same backlog and iterations, but hide the sensitive one from some team members?

**Thanks in advance for your time!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding permission of work items in a team project, you can set the permission in area and iteration scope, but can’t for specific work items.

So, you need to put these work items in different area and manage permission for this area. Simple steps:

1. Go to team project admin page
2. Work=>Areas
3. Click New/New child, to create a new area.
4. Click …=>Security, set the permission for the group(s) or user(s)
5. Click the default team’s settings => Areas
6. Click + Select areas to add that area in order to show related work items (in that area)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'd read about areas and played with them before asking, but it seemed difficult or impossible to keep work items in a centralised pipeline using this approach.

I'll give your suggestion and steps a go tomorrow and get back to you :)

Comment: @M0053 What do you mean centralised pipeline? Could you provide the sample to explain it?

Comment: Ok, I've had another dig into the areas concept and it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I will elaborate my original question above.

Comment: @M0053 Base on your update, put the work item (contains sensitive information ) in a special area could meet the requirement, the work items in different areas could show in the same backlog list, what's the problem?

Comment: I must be missing something obvious here, sorry! When adding a work item to the second area (nested under the original default area), it is hidden from the original backlog, and only appears in a second backlog named after that area. Is there a setting to force the two areas to use the same backlog?

Comment: @M0053 You need to add that area to the team (step 5, 6).

Comment: I had made a mistake with the security permissions :) Thanks for your help @starain-MSFT